# Password authentication issue with PostgreSQL in GitHub Actions. Python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, github-actions, asyncpg

I try to run integration tests in GitHub Actions. For this want to create a postgresql database and connect to it. The code for posrtgresql service I took [from here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/creating-postgresql-service-containers). The code which connects to the database works perfectly fine when I start the DB some other way (by docker-compose for example).
However when I try local Actions runner or upload my code to GitHub I get this error:
 `asyncpg.exceptions.InvalidPasswordError: password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

I've tried to simplify my code and remove anything except most crucial parts. However the issue stays the same. I feel that the root cause for it is that service container is started with some other password in mind, and hence rejects my auth attempt.

This is my simplified .yml file:

```
name: Temporary Test Workflow

jobs:
  temp_test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: python:3.11-buster
    services:
      postgres:
        # Docker Hub image
        image: postgres
        # Provide the password for postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_DB: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        # Set health checks to wait until postgres has started
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: connect_and_test
        run: |
          pip install pipenv
          pipenv install --deploy --system --dev
          python -m connection_test
```

This is my simplified connection_test.py

```
import asyncio

import asyncpg


async def main():
    db_url = (
        f"postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres"
    )
    print(f"Starting connection on '{db_url}'")
    conn = await asyncpg.connect(db_url)
    print(await conn.execute("select 'OK'"))
    await conn.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I also tried to use sync and async engines of sqlalchemy to connect. No luck as well, I get roughly the same error - my password is incorrect. What in my setup could be wrong?

Edit:
Also I tried to use `postgres` as hostname. I got following error: `socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`. So probably `localhost` is the correct host value for me.

Comment: Did you try using `postgres` as host instead of `localhost` as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/creating-postgresql-service-containers)?

Comment: @Azeem Yes, and I got another error `socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`. 
Correct me if I wrong, it seems that asyncpg did not find a database on that host.

Comment: See [this](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#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).

Comment: Tried to reproduce your scenario [here](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/5699924856/job/15449295593) and it's working fine with `postgres` host.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with `act` [a local github runner](https://github.com/nektos/act).

I have not yet found why, but it seems that while running locally the `postgres` host does not work and the database is somewhere else. It seems to be found on `localhost`, however the password does not match.

I tried with [this](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#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) code of Azeem, and it also works in Github Actions, and does not in local github runner.

Comment: The [`services`](https://github.com/nektos/act#services) are not supported by act at the moment.